# Tapestry: set css class of a Grid column

Tags: css, grid, tapestry

I'd like to specify the css class that the Tapestry Grid component assigns to the TH and TD tags in a column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

And the long answer is yes!

If the class attributes, mentioned in Steve Enyon's answer, are not enough you can decorate the DOM after the grid has rendered via a mixin. I have created a GridDecorator mixin [here](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/stitch/mixins/GridDecorator.java) which can decorate `TR` and `TD` elements based on the value in the cell / row. In my example I add `onclick` and `style` attributes to the DOM. You could easily tweak the mixin to decorate `TH` elements with a GridHeaderCellDecorator and add `class` attributes where necessary.

My 2p, I think that the Grid is long overdue for an overhaul and that customisations like this should be much easier than they are.

Comment: That's a good trick, although I'd deem it a last resort. I once wrote a mixin that attached itself to the Grid pager, deleted all DOM elements the pager produced and re-rendered the HTML as I saw fit! Why? That was the only way to alter the pager HTML without replacing the whole Grid mechanism. It worked well though! I do like the way you can manipulate practically everything in T5!

Comment: The demo link is dead, any chance you could post it again?

Comment: See [GridDecorator.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/stitch/mixins/GridDecorator.java), [GridDecoratorDemo.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch-demo/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/stitch/demo/pages/GridDecoratorDemo.java) and [GridDecoratorDemo.tml](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/tapestry-stitch-demo/src/main/resources/org/lazan/t5/stitch/demo/pages/GridDecoratorDemo.tml)

Comment: Still works, though I had to change *find("table/tbody")* to *find("tbody")* with T54

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

What Tapestry does do though is give each column a unique css class based on the property it represents. You can then style this class any way you want.

For example, if you had a `Grid` of `User` classes:

```java
public class User {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

```html
<t:grid source="users" />
```

Tapestry would produce HTML similar to:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="firstName">First Name</th>
            <th class="lastName">Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
        <tr>
            <td class="firstName">Traci</td>
            <td class="lastName">Lords</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See the `CSS` section at the bottom of the [Grid API page](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.html) for more details.

If you have some common styling that you'd like to apply to specific columns, and you happen to be using [less](http://lesscss.org/), then you could use `less mixins` (not to be confused with Tapestry mixins). From the Less website:

> Mixins allow you to embed all the properties of a class into another
>   class by simply including the class name as one of its properties